# NTP tool for showing deviance to a certain server

Tags: time, ntp

I am searching for a command-line that allows me to check the system time deviance to a NTP server specified on the command-line. I don't want to change/adapt the system time - only displays the deviance.

Nice would be an text-mode display as it is used by the windows tool w32tm.exe:

```
14:09:06 d:+00.0331970s o:+00.0046684s [                           *                           ]
14:09:08 d:+00.0331985s o:+00.0050307s [                           *                           ]
14:09:10 d:+00.0331980s o:+00.0050342s [                           *                           ]
14:09:12 d:+00.0341736s o:+00.0041995s [                           *                           ]
14:09:14 d:+00.0341737s o:+00.0048171s [                           *                           ]
14:09:16 d:+00.0331742s o:+00.0043771s [                           *                           ]
14:09:18 d:+00.0341740s o:+00.0045760s [                           *                           ]
```

What program should I use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ ntpdate -q pool.ntp.org
server 86.59.113.118, stratum 2, offset 0.007942, delay 0.07298
server 147.251.48.140, stratum 2, offset -0.001173, delay 0.05101
server 212.18.3.19, stratum 2, offset -0.003886, delay 0.04689
```

Answer (score 1):

ntpdate is going away. you can do the same thing moving forward with sntp